# Developing SSIS in Visual studio (32 bit) on a 64 bit OS - Cannot use the OLE DB Driver for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I need to use the OLE DB Driver for SQL Server in an SSIS package, but I cannot as visual studio is 32bit and the computer has a 64bit os.

The OS I am using is 64 bit (windows 10 64 bit and windows server 2016 64 bit).
This means I can only install the 64 bit driver.

The latest Visual Studio that SSIS runs on is 2017, which is only 32 bit, meaning it can only use the 32 bit driver.

If i want to use the OLE DB Driver for SQL Server, is my only option to install visual studio 2017 on a 32 bit pc and develop from there?

Comment: *"The OS I am using is 64 bit (windows 10 64 bit and windows server 2016 64 bit). This means I can only install the 64 bit driver."* This statement alone is wrong.

Comment: *"The latest Visual Studio that SSIS runs on is 2017,"* Also incorrect, SSIS is available on both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022.

Comment: Honestly, I have never had to manually install the OLEDB driver either. I literally set up a new work PC last week, and installed SSMS, VS 2019 and 2022 and have been working fine. I didn't need to find and download the OLEDB driver, and I've worked in both 64-bit and 32-bit packages on the new device. This feels like you haven't actually tried doing the work you want/need to do.

Comment: @ThomA Could you be more specific about what is wrong with the statement. 
I downloaded the 32 bit and 64 bit drivers to my 64 bit system. The 64 bit driver installs without issue, the 32 bit throw's an error "the installation of this product failed because it is not supported on this system"

Comment: @ThomA I have installed visual studio 2022 & the ssis plugin "SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022" which is in version 0.3 right now.

The packages do not open, they just throw lots and lots of errors. I will start looking at these, but seeing the number of them i decided to ask here first.

Comment: @ThomA I have indeed tried. Your answer is not helpful and likely not within posting requirements. i have spelled out the problem, just because you have not faced it does not mean it has not manifested. "works on my pc" is a pretty poor response.

Comment: As for trying, if you're getting errors, why are you not demonstrating those in your question? It seems like that is the *real* problem you need to solve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64bit installer for msoledbsql installs both the 64bit and 32bit driver, but the installer for [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist) does not.  So go install the 32bit Visual C++ Redistributable.

Normally you would already have this after you install Visual Studio, but you're using an older Visual Studio.

Or better, you can use the new [SSIS tools for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices), and the main Visual Studio process is 64bit starting with 2022, so you don't need to use the 32bit drivers any more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You must use the 32bit OLEDB driver with VS2017. SSIS also works with the combo of VS2019 16.8.5 and Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices V3.11.1

Irritatingly, SQL/Server uses the 64 bit one. You are supposed to be able to install both and there's any number of articles telling you how but I've never managed it so I gave up. I rarely use SQL/Server on my dev machine anyway but occasionally it's been useful. When I want to run an SSIS package under SQL/Server I have to remove the 32 bit one and install the 64 bit one.